# In git, obtain commits using git log with path

Tags: git, path, git-commit, git-log

I would like to obtain the last 10 commits using git log specifying the path of my repository. I used the option `-path` but I have "is outside repository" error

```
 git log --no-merges -10 -p /home/my_folder/git/repo

 fatal: /home/my_folder/git/repo: '/home/my_folder/git/repo' is outside repository
```

The comand is running for example in the folder /home

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Git assumes that the current working directory is inside the repository you want to operate on.  When running a git command from outside the repository directory hierarchy, you can use the global `-C` option to git to specify which repository to use:

```
git -C /home/my_folder/git/repo log --no-merges -10 -p
```

Usually it's probably easier to simply `cd` to your repository before running git commands.

Comment: *When running a git command from outside the repository directory hierarchy [...]* Do you mean "from outside *any* repo"? The error message indicates that the OP runs that `git log` command from within *some* repo; otherwise s/he would have gotten *fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git*.

Comment: @Jubobs: As stated in the first sentence of my answer, I meant from outside the repo you want to operate on.  Whether you are in a different repo or not is immaterial – you will have to tell git what repository to use either way.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that the `-C` flag for `git log` only appeared starting from **git 1.8.5 and up** https://git-scm.com/docs/git/1.8.5

For older versions of git here are your options:

1.Manually move to the directory:

```
cd /home/my_folder/git/repo && git log --no-merges -10 && cd -
```

2.Specify the `--git-dir` parameter:

```
git --git-dir /home/my_folder/git/repo/.git log --no-merges -10
```